# Custom error level on trigger_error()

Tags: php, error-handling

Is it good practice to use custom error levels on `trigger_error()`?

For example, can I do:

```
define('E_MY_LEVEL', 3);
...
trigger_error('Hey this error occurs every time!', E_MY_LEVEL);
```

? Consider that 3 is not a [PHP Error level value](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php) so it doesn't go in conflict with the other levels.

*(I want to do this so that I don't have to create another function that requires other code rather than the one I've already written in the `error_handler` function I associated to `set_error_handler()`.)*

Comment: If your error handler is a custom one and knows about all the assigned magic values, doesn't inspect the incoming integer as bit field, then yes, that's feasible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to say whether this is good practice or not, but 3 does exist as a PHP Error Level Value -

```
error_reporting( E_ERROR | E_WARNING ); // E_ERROR | E_WARNING = 3
```

Also not knowing what your trigger() function is, trigger_error needs an error level in the E_USER range... maybe it would be best to use E_USER_NOTICE? (1024)

Comment: I typed it wrong. I mean `trigger_error()` the native one. But yes, you are right, 3 i an error level value. Maybe I could use negative values?

Answer (score 1):

The basic E_XXX error code flags typically are based on powers of two, e.g. 1 2 4 8 16 32 etc.

If you find an unused power of two, you can use that one.

Because 3 = 1 + 2 is the sum of two powers of two, it counts as using two flags,  E_ERROR | E_WARNING.